# How to add @Ressource from TomEE to Jboss

Tags: java, xml, jboss, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

Im trying to migrate an application from TomEE to Jboss.

I found some injection of Ressource :

```
@Resource(name = "SaraConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory saraConnectionFactory;

@Resource(name = "SaraToOlsQueue")
private Queue saraQueue;

@Resource(name = "SaraTargetService")
private String service;

@Resource(name = "SaraTimeout")
private long timeout;
```

The statement are in TomEE.xml like this :

```
    <Resource id="SaraJMSResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    <!--BrokerXmlConfig -->
    ServerUrl tcp://bdv06:61616
     </Resource>

    <Resource id="SaraToOlsQueue" type="javax.jms.Queue">
    destination RMW
    </Resource>

    <Connector id="SaraConnectionFactory"type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
    ResourceAdapter SaraJMSResourceAdapter

    # Specifies if the connection is enrolled in global transaction
    TransactionSupport none

    # Maximum number of physical connection to the ActiveMQ broker
    PoolMaxSize 10

    # Minimum number of physical connection to the ActiveMQ broker
    PoolMinSize 0

    # Maximum amount of time to wait for a connection
    ConnectionMaxWaitMilliseconds 10000

    # Maximum amount of time a connection can be idle before being reclaimed
    ConnectionMaxIdleMinutes 15
    </Connector>
```

How can i translate these tag to the standalone.xml ( Jboss).

Thxs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way to simulate an activeMQ into JBOSS.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="resourceAdapterForSara">
                <module slot="main" id="org.apache.activemq"/>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                    tcp://cdjactivemq:3030
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/connectionFactoryForSara" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="connectionFactoryForSara">
                        <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                        </xa-pool>
                        <recovery>
                            <recover-credential>
                                <user-name>admin</user-name>
                                <password>admin</password>
                            </recover-credential>
                        </recovery>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```